# Disassemble into x86_64 on OSX10.6 (But with _Intel_ Syntax)

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, x86-64

I know of `otool -tv`, but I would much rather use the *Intel* syntax rather than AT&Ts, mainly to easily follow along in a book and not have to look over thousands of `%`'s and `$`'s.

I'd also appreciate any tips to where I might find `gdb`'s config file.

EDIT: I forgot: I'm running a 64bit processor, but was wondering if it would be possible to also disassemble into 32 bit assembly? Not only that, but does OSX's `gdb`'s `list` command work differently than the standard `GNU` version?

Thanks so much!

(Also, if you have any idea where I might find a little disassembler from C -> MIPS, that'd be very fun to play with. But not necessary!)

Comment: C -> MIPS isn't disassembly, that's compilation.  C is "high level" source, not machine code.  https://godbolt.org/ (the compiler explorer) has MIPS GCC installed, and with clang you can use `-O3 -target mips` or `-O3 -target mips64`.  If Apple Clang on MacOS is built with support, you might be able to use `clang -target mips -S` on your desktop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your second question, if the code has been compiled into a fat binary with both 64-bit and 32-bit, you can use `otool -arch i386 -tv` to disassemble the 32-bit slice of the binary; `otool -arch x86_64 -tv` will give you the 64-bit portion (on SnowLeopard, this is also the default behavior if no `-arch` flag is passed).

Also note that while otool doesn't support the Intel syntax, gdb (`set disassembly-flavor intel`) and XCode (Preferences -> Debugging -> Disassembly Style) do.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with this, though I'm still curious about MIPS :) 

Too bad about `otool` not supporting Intel's syntax.

Comment: If it's an obstacle for you, you should file a bug requesting that the feature be added (you'll need to set up an ADC account if you don't already have one): developer.apple.com/BugReporter

Answer (score 8):

(I know this is an old question, but I want to provide an updated answer for people who come here through search engines).

On recent versions of macOS (I'm running 10.14.5), an `objdump` command is available, which is based on LLVM and is *not* the one from the GNU project. It offers a (hidden) option to disassemble using Intel syntax. For example, `/bin/echo` can be disassembled as follows:

```
objdump -disassemble -x86-asm-syntax=intel /bin/echo
```

Comment: That's `llvm-objdump`.  On my Linux system, `llvm-objdump` comes with clang/llvm packages, and takes those options.  Manual: https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-objdump.html

Answer (score 1):

With [Objdump](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html) you can disassemble with `-d -M intel`, and apparently `-m` can be used to specify the architecture.

Comment: I understand that - unfortunately objdump doesn't work on/doesn't come with OSX.

Comment: I believe you can get objdump on OSX if you install gdb binutils using macports or homebrew. I had it at one point but I preferred to use otool since it is actually an OSX tool. I agree though, would like the intel syntax in otool itself.

Comment: If you do install binutils using homebrew, the name of the executable is gobjdump.  It is a bit flaky and crashes after generating the output but... it's better than nothing!

Comment: I have a version of objdump on mac but I couldn't make it disassemble x64 code

Answer (score 1):

For GDB, in your .gdbinit file, add:

> set disassembly-flavor intel

then it will be the default syntax for gdb.

Answer (score 0):

You can use A2I to translate from AT&T to Intel syntax: http://membres.lycos.fr/placr/a2i.html

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for – the syntaxes are both easy enough to read. It's more a matter of making my life easier; using A2I adds steps I'd rather not take, for little reward. Thank you though!

Comment: This link is now broken.