# how to update objdump? got: unknown command line argument -M

Tags: macos, x86-64, disassembly, objdump, intel-syntax

Working through Jon Erickson's book on Hacking. He uses an intel format assembly code. He provides the following snippet:

```
reader@hacking:~/booksrc 08048374 <main>:
$ objdump -M intel -D
a.out | grep -A20 main.
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Mac-of-Thor:test thorkamphefner$ objdump -M
objdump: Unknown command line argument '-M'.  Try: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/objdump -help'
objdump: Did you mean '-C'?
```

What do I need to do to update objdump?

Comment: `objdump` might not be the appropriate tool for working on a Mac...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objdump` on a Mac is [`llvm-objdump`](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-objdump.html), not GNU Binutils `objdump` that takes command-line options like `-Mintel`

I think I've read that the standard ways of installing GNU binutils on Mac will give you `gobjdump`.

---

See [Disassemble into x86_64 on OSX10.6 (But with _Intel_ Syntax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727958/disassemble-into-x86-64-on-osx10-6-but-with-intel-syntax/56890343#56890343)
`objdump -disassemble -x86-asm-syntax=intel` should work on a Mac (for llvm-objdump).

Comment: Annoying that they're different, but this got the job done. Thanks.